# onCheckChanged is only called the first time

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, oncheckedchanged

I want to get a value from checking a RadioButton. I have three RadioButton (with different values) inside a RadioGroup. Well, the first time I check a RadioButton I am able to get the value, but if I change to another RadioButton I cannot get values anymore. It is like if onCheckedChanged is only call the first time I check a RadioButton.

Any helpful will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
 public class AsesorNutri extends AppCompatActivity {


RadioGroup deporte;
RadioButton andar;
RadioButton correr;
RadioButton ciclismo;
String TAG="";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_asesor_nutri);
    andar=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.andar);
    andar.setChecked(true);
    correr=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.correr);
    ciclismo=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.ciclismo);
     deporte = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.deporte);


    deporte.setOnCheckedChangeListener(cambiodeporte);

}

     public RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener cambiodeporte=new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int i) {
             switch(i)
             {
                 case R.id.andar:
                     Log.i(TAG, "cambia andar");

                     // do what you wan there
                     break;
                 case R.id.correr:
                     Log.i(TAG, "cambia correr");

                     break;

                 case R.id.ciclismo:
                     Log.i(TAG, "cambia correr");


                     break;
             }
         }
     };



 }
```

And this is my layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/MainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"

tools:context="lnspad.fitnessup.AsesorNutri">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
    android:text="Seleccione  Deporte"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/deporte"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/andar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/deporte"
        android:text="Andar" />



<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/correr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Correr"
    android:layout_marginEnd="39dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ciclismo"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ciclismo"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ciclismo" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/ciclismo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ciclismo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/deporte"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="49dp" />


     </RadioGroup>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Type your layout too, please.

Comment: @CoolMind Layout posted

Answer (score 0):

Your code is odd. Not sure why you have public access modifier on the listener. Why not define it the same way as you have the other variables? The annotation claims it's a resource ID, and it's constant, so it has to work. Otherwise, it could be a lifecycle issue because you're initializing in onCreate().

EG:

```
RadioGroup deporte;
RadioButton andar;
RadioButton correr;
RadioButton ciclismo;
RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener cambiodeporte;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_asesor_nutri);
    andar=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.andar);
    andar.setChecked(true);
    correr=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.correr);
    ciclismo=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.ciclismo);
    deporte = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.deporte);
    cambiodeporte = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int i) {
         switch(i)
         {
             case R.id.andar:
                 Log.i(TAG, "cambia andar");

                 // do what you wan there
                 break;
             case R.id.correr:
                 Log.i(TAG, "cambia correr");

                 break;

             case R.id.ciclismo:
                 Log.i(TAG, "cambia correr");


                 break;
             }
         }
    };

    deporte.setOnCheckedChangeListener(cambiodeporte);
}
```

Comment: @a person It doesn't work. Same behaviour. I don't know if the fact that this activity is started from the MainActivity  has any relation to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You code works. I changed a bit and showed toasts.

```
private RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener cambiodeporte=new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case R.id.andar:
                Log.i(TAG, "cambia andar");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "1. cambia andar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
            case R.id.correr:
                Log.i(TAG, "cambia correr");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "2. cambia correr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;

            case R.id.ciclismo:
                Log.i(TAG, "cambia ciclismo");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "3. cambia ciclismo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Maybe it's a device problem.

Comment: Yes...it works. I think the problem was that the Log doesn't work. That was the reason why I bellieved it wasn't working. Toast shows that the code works. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @ilpadrino, I also noticed you Logs contained wrong values ("cambia correr" in two cases). So, I changed Logs and added toasts.